# Confused about the definition of convex drawing of plane graph

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

When I looked up the definition of convex drawing of planar graph, my confusion mainly focused on the outer face.

The following definition of convex drawing  is from Wikipedia.

> In graph drawing, a **convex drawing** of a planar graph is a drawing that represents the vertices of the graph as points in the Euclidean plane and the edges as straight line segments, in such a way that all of the faces of the drawing (**including the outer face**) have a convex boundary.

It gives two examples

[image]

Surprisingly, the outer face is not convex in the second example.
[image]

I 'd like to ask what is the convex boundary of outer face here? The outer face doesn't seem to be convex and I feel that **the unbounded face is the complement of a convex set.**

So **I'm confused by the definition of convex drawing where  boundary  of the outer face is also convex**. I don't know where I got it wrong.

I searched the Mathemaics Stack for a similar puzzle below. There seems to be no consensus.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940693/convex-planar-graphs

Comment: I believe the operative phrase in the definition is “have a convex boundary”. The definition does not say that the faces must be convex sets, but rather that the boundary of each face must be convex (i.e., must bound a convex region in its interior).

Comment: @dwilburne I see. Thank you! I confused the polygons formed by the edges of the outer face with the outer face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia does not state that the outerface is convex, but rather that it has a convex boundary.  I assume this means that the set consisting of all points inside the boundary is convex.  So for example, the outerface has a convex boundary in your two examples.  Also, with this definition, it is true that every $3$-connected planar graph has a convex drawing (since it is the $1$-skeleton of a $3$-polytope).